# Curb giving me weird error

Tags: ruby, windows, curl, libcurl, curb

I installed `curb on ruby` with this line of code and it said that it installed ok.

```
C:\>gem install curb --platform=ruby -- --with-curl-lib=C:\curl\bin --with-curl-include=D:\curl\include
```

Then I go to run a script that has `require 'curb'` at the top and I get an error saying 
`the procedure entry point curl_easy_escape could not be located in the dynamic link library libcurl.dll`

Anyone know what this error means? I can't find any information on it online.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to update your libcurl.dll